# Is there any way where I could add the previous random number with next random number?

Tags: python, random

I have a list mixture of digit and alpha.

```
import random

def main():
 list: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','a','b','c']

 for count in range (1,5):
   serial_no=("serial #: ", count)
   totallist=0

   from random import choice:
   number=choice(list)

   print(serial_no+'for the time: '+number)

   if number.isdigit() and number<4:
      totallist+=int(number) # want to add the first number >4

   elif number.isdigit()and number>4:
      totallist+=int(number)

   elif number.isalpha():
      list[9]=0
      list[-1]=0
      totallist=int(list[9])+int(list[-1]) #I could not add (error) (want to add alpha(as 0) and number after being alpha)
   print(totallist)

main()
```

is there any way I could add the first random number>4 to the total random number of number<4?

Thanks

Comment: Your example contains syntax errors. Please fix them.

Comment: There seem to be many syntax errors in your code, and it's very unclear what you want to do.  Could you try fixing your code and rewrite the question so that it's clear what you want to achieve?

Comment: Actually it contains at least three syntax errors and a number of invalid operations (after fixing all the obvious syntax errors I'm still left with `TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple`.)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this is what you wanted, but this is as close as I could come to fixing your syntax errors and formatting and also guess at what you wanted to achieve (hoping for an `A` for effort here):

```
import random

def safe_index(li, i):
   try:
      return li[i]
   except:
      return 0

def main():
   list = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','a','b','c']
   totallist = []

   for count in range (1,5):
      serial_no = "serial #%s: " % count

      number = random.choice(list)

      print('%s for the time: %s' % (serial_no, number))

      if number.isdigit() and int(number) < 4:
         print('<4')

         # add digit to first number in series >= 4
         totallist.append(int(number) + 
                          safe_index(filter(lambda x: x >= 4, totallist), 0))

      elif number.isdigit() and int(number) >= 4:
         print('>=4')
         totallist.append(int(number))

      elif number.isalpha():
         print('alpha')

         # convert alpha to ordinal number
         totallist.append(ord(number) - (ord('a') - 1))

   print(totallist)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Sample output:

```
serial #1:  for the time: 5
>=4
serial #2:  for the time: 2
<4
serial #3:  for the time: 6
>=4
serial #4:  for the time: a
alpha
[5, 7, 6, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it is not the answer that I want